# An alternative to dynamically added scripts

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to add and remove JS files. I've found a very ugly solution but it seems to work as expected: loading iframes 'as scripts'... hey folks, it's nothing more than an experimentation :-)

loadJS.html

```
 <iframe id="script"></iframe>
 <script>


    let s = document.getElementById('script');
    s.setAttribute("src","loadJS.js"); // open 1st JS file in iframe

    setTimeout( function(){     
        let c = s.contentWindow.document.documentElement.innerText; // get content as text
        alert(c); // get it
        let x = Function(c); x(); // use text as function
    } ,100);

    setTimeout( function(){ 
        s.setAttribute("src","newJS.js"); // 2nd JS script
    } ,8000);

    setTimeout( function(){ 
        let d = s.contentWindow.document.documentElement.innerText; 
        alert(d)
        let y = Function(d); y();
    } ,8100);


</script>
```

loadJS.js

```
 g('');
 function g(m) { console.log('Function g() '+m+'loaded'); h(0); }
 function h(n) { setTimeout(function(){ g('re') },2000); }
```

newJS.js

```
 console.log('load new Script'); let n=0; g(n);
 function g(n) { if(n<3) { console.log('new Script g() value = '+n); h(); }}
 function h() { setTimeout(function(){ g(n+=1) },2000); }
```

console.log on page load:

```
Function g() loaded
Function g() reloaded
Function g() reloaded
...
```

console.log after 8 sec:

```
 load new Script
 new Script g() value = 0
 Function g() reloaded
 new Script g() value = 1
 Function g() reloaded
 new Script g() value = 2
 Function g() reloaded
 Function g() reloaded
 ...
```

Is there a way to reinit / remove / destroy / replace g() function from 1st script once the 2nd is loaded?

Comment: This is just a very convoluted AJAX + eval. Just use `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest` then eval the script. There is really no security difference between `eval` and `Function()` except that your intention is clearer when you use `eval`. If you are afraid about people saying don't use `eval` than you are missing the point that that advice also applies to `Function()` etc. - any eval-like feature.

Comment: Thx. I usually use Fetch in production but it's a pure experimentation.

Comment: TBH the more appropriate way is to dynamically add a `script` tag. It's what the big boys like jQuery & google maps do. The tag even has an `onload` event that triggers once it's been downloaded and executed.

Comment: except it's impossible to remove a dynamically added a script, once loaded it remains in memory: removeChild() has no effect on scripts. That's the reason why I'm trying to experiment others possibilities.

Comment: Well, the same is true for your method. Removing the iframe does not delete objects in memory

Comment: ...but the script #1 doesn't send no more datas after loading script#2 (see console in my answer below). How to make sure it's really removed from memory ?

Answer (score 0):

OK it works

loadJS.html

```
  let x = document.getElementById('script');
  x.setAttribute("src","loadJS.js"); 

  setTimeout( function(){   
        let y = x.contentWindow.document.documentElement.innerText; // JS as text
        let z = Function(y); z(); // exec
  } ,200);

  function change(){ 
        x.setAttribute("src","newJS.js"); 
        setTimeout( function(){ 
            let y = x.contentWindow.document.documentElement.innerText; 
            let z = Function(y); z();
        } ,200);
    }
```

loadJS.js

```
   g(0); 
   function g(n) { console.log('Script loadJS.js -> Function g('+n+')'); n+=1; h(n); }
   function h(n) { 
      if(n==3) { parent.change(); }
      else { setTimeout(function(){ g(n) },2000); } // make sure script is really removed
   }
```

newJS.js

```
   console.log('load new Script'); let n=0; g(n);
   function g(n) { if(n<3) { console.log('Script newJS.js -> Function  g('+n+')'); h(); }}
   function h() { setTimeout(function(){ g(n+=1) },2000); }
```

console

```
   Script loadJS.js -> Function g(0)
   Script loadJS.js -> Function g(1)
   Script loadJS.js -> Function g(2)
   load new Script
   Script newJS.js -> Function  g(0)
   Script newJS.js -> Function  g(1)
   Script newJS.js -> Function  g(2)
```

...because removeChild() can remove anything in DOM except scripts.

Comment: But even if you remove your iframe `g(0)` can still be executed. You will not remove the `g()` function from memory either way

Comment: yes but I change its value: g() of script #1 is replaced with the g() script#2 or I'm wrong ?

Comment: Yes but that is the same with how `script` tag works